# How is this a valid Java method invocation?

Tags: java, methods, invocation

I've just been reading Marko Rodriguez's [excellent blog post](http://markorodriguez.com/2011/04/30/putting-and-getting-data-from-a-database/) about different types of databases. Whilst reading I noticed some syntax...

```
// put data
db.put('marko');
db.put(31);
db.put(true);
// get data
Iterator results = db.get();
Iterator filteredResults = db.get{it.startsWith('ma')};
```

...which I presumed was a snippet of Java, but I've never seen a method invoked using curly braces like this before - `db.get{it.startsWith('ma')}`.

Any details/thoughts on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks like it's probably Groovy (using closures) rather than Java. Note that it also uses `'marko'` which isn't valid Java. (Java uses single quotes for *character* literals, not *string* literals.)

That would also fit with the author's involvement in [Gremlin](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki), which is written in Groovy.

Comment: I was wondering why <b>marko</b> wouldn't be valid, but at second glance see that it is the single quotes that are the problem. Yes, this looks like groovy.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have spotted the string/character literal difference. I didn't realise Gremlin was written in Groovy either. Cheers guys!